# Play a youtube video when an image is clicked and go back to the image when video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an website where my client wants to be able to play an youtube video when he clicks an image and when the video finishes, the video disappears and the same image reappears again.

For example, view the website below and click the image on the home page.
https://www.oldbankruptcypapers.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below approach to achieve that :

When you click on the image, hide it and make your player container div visible. Bind **onStateChange** event of your YT Player to check for video ending and then hide the player or remove it and make your image visible.

Below is the code snippet :

```
<img src="http://d3gnp09177mxuh.cloudfront.net/tech-page-images/java.png" id="javaImg">
<div id="playerContainer">
  <div id="player" width="300" align="left" height="238" style="margin-right:30px;"></div>
</div>

$("#javaImg").click(function(){
if($("#player").is("div"))
{
  $(this).hide();
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '335',
    width: '596',
    playerVars: { 'controls': 1,'autohide':1},
    videoId: 'r59xYe3Vyks',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });

}
  else {
    player.autohide=1;
    player.playVideo();
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  } 

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {            
      $("#player").remove(); 
      $("#playerContainer").append('<div id ="player" width="300" align="left" height="238" style="margin-right:30px;"></div>');
      $("#javaImg").show();
    }
  }
});
```

I have also created a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/qLzpg27g/

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the youtube Iframe API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to resolve this.

Here is the example script:

```
$('#yourImage').on('click', function () {
    var player = new YT.Player('yourDivToAppendVideo', {
        // height: '1080',
        // width: '1920',
        videoId: 'putVideoIdHere',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
            // and other options
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': function (event) {
                // Write your logic to HIDE the image here
                event.target.playVideo(); // play video
            },
            'onStateChange': function (event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    // Write your logic to UNHIDE the image here
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API :

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
            if(event.data === 0) {          
                //replace video with image
            }

//status states from API
  // -1 – unstarted
  // 0 – ended
  // 1 – playing
  // 2 – paused
  // 3 – buffering
  // 5 - Video Cued
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information